# Runtime exception, store address not aligned on word boundary

Tags: alignment, mips, mars-simulator

```
.text  
.globl main  

main:  
addi $v0, $0, 4  
la $a0, msg_dimensions_matrix  
syscall
li $v0, 5                           # Scans N (size of matrix).  
syscall  
move $s7, $v0                       # Stores given matrix size in $s7.  
addi $v0, $0, 4  
la $a0, msg_fill  
syscall   
addi $t0, $0, 0                     # Initializes counter (stored in $t0).  
move $a0, $t0                       # Moves counter to $a0.  
mul $a3, $s7, $s7     
mul $a3, $a3, 4               
jal input_loop_0                    # Calls function input_loop to fill the matrix.  
addi $v0, $0, 4  
la $a0, msg_dimensions_subm  
syscall  
li $v0, 5                           # Scans M (size of submatrix).  
syscall  
move $s6, $v0                       # Stores submatrix size in $s6.  
addi $v0, $0, 4  
la $a0, msg_leftdist  
syscall  
li $v0, 5                           # Scans left distance.  
syscall  
move $s4, $v0                       # Stores left distance in $s4.  
li $v0, 5                           # Scans upper distance.  
syscall  
move $s5, $v0                       # Stores upper distance in $s5.  
move $a0, $s5                       # Stores upper distance in $a0.  
move $a1, $s4                       # Stores left distance in $a1.  
move $a2, $s6                       # Stores submatrix size in $a2.  
move $a3, $s7                       # Stores matrix size in $a3.  
jal submatrix_transpos  
j matrix_copy_0  

input_loop_0:  
addi $v0, $0, 4  
la $a0, msg_input  
syscall  
li $v0, 5  
syscall  
move $t1, $v0                       # Stores user input in $t1.  
la $t7, init_matrix    
add $t7, $0, $a0                   
sw $t1, 0($t7)                      # Stores user input properly in matrix.  
addi $a0, $a0, 4                    # Increases row counter by 4 bytes.  
bne $t7, $a3, input_loop_0          # If row counter is not equal to matrix size, jumps to loop.  
jr $ra  

submatrix_transpos:   
la $t0, init_matrix  
mul $t2, $a2, $a0                  # M * i  
add $t2, $t2, $a1                  # (M * i) + j  
add $t0, $t0, $t2                  # A  + ((M * i) + j)  
la $t1, submatrix  
#addi $t1, $0, $t0                   # A  + ((M * i) + j)  
add $s3, $0, $t0                     
addi $t4, $0, 0  
addi $t7, $0, 4                     # $t7 = 4.  
mul $s1, $a3, $t7                  # Calculates how many bytes each row of the initial matrix has.  
mul $t9, $a2, $t7  
mul $t5, $s1, $a3  
add $s6, $t0, $t5       
add $s6, $s6, $t9                   # Stores position of bottom right element of submatrix, to be used to break from loop when bounds are reached.  
addi $s7, $0, 0                     # Number of times loop has been performed set to 0.  

submatrix_loop:  
lw $t8, init_matrix  
sw $t8, submatrix  
addi $t1, $t1, 4                    # submatrix[j + 1]  
add $t0, $t0, $s1                   # matrix [i + 1]  
addi $t4, $t4, 1                    # Increases counter of times i or j is increased, by 1.   
beq $t0, $s6, return                # If bottom right corner of submatrix is reached, return.  
beq $t4, $a2, reset0                # If i or j reaches submatrix bounds, reset accordingly.    
j submatrix_loop                    # Else, then continue.  

reset0:  
la $t0, init_matrix  
add $t0, $0, $s3  
la $t1, submatrix  
add $t0, $0, $s3  

return:  
jr $ra  

matrix_copy_0:  
la $t0, init_matrix                 # Load address of initial matrix.  
la $t1, final_matrix                # Load address of final matrix.  
addi $t2, $0, 0                     # Initialize counter to 0.  
addi $t3, $0, 0  
add $t4, $s7, $s7                  # Size NxN of matrix.  
for0:  
lw $t3, init_matrix  
sw $t3, final_matrix  
addi $t2, $t2, 4                    # Increase counter by 4 bytes.  
addi $t3, $t3, 1  
beq $t4, $t3, matrix_copy_1  
j for0  

matrix_copy_1:  
la $t0, final_matrix  
mul $t2, $s6, $s5                  # M * i  
add $t2, $t2, $s4                  # (M * i) + j  
add $t0, $t0, $t2                  # A  + ((M * i) + j)  
la $t1, submatrix  
addi $t8, $0, 0  
addi $t3, $0, 0  
mul $t7, $s7, 4  
for1:  
lw $t4, submatrix  
sw $t4, final_matrix  
addi $t0, $t0, 4  
addi $t1, $t1, 4  
addi $t8, $0, 1  
beq $s6, $t8, reset1  
j for1  

reset1:  
la $t0, final_matrix  
mul $t2, $s6, $s5                  # M * i  
add $t2, $t2, $s4                  # (M * i) + j  
add $t0, $t0, $t2                  # A  + ((M * i) + j)  
add $t0, $t0, $t7  
addi $t3, $t3, 1                    # Times in this label increased by one.  
beq $t3, $s6, print  
j for1  

print:  
addi $v0, $0, 4  
la $a0, msg_final  
syscall  
la $t0, final_matrix  
addi $t1, $0, 0  
addi $t4, $0, 0                     # Output counter, change line every   
addi $t5, $0, 5                     # 5 printed integers.  
for2:  
lw $t3, final_matrix  
li $v0, 1                           # Print content.  
add $a0, $t3, $0  
syscall  
addi $t0, $t0, 4   
addi $t4, $t4, 1  
beq $t1, $s7, exit  
beq $t4, $t5, reset2  
j for2  

reset2:  
addi $v0, $0, 4  
la $a0, newline  
syscall  
addi $t4, $t4, 0  

j for2  

exit:  
li $v0, 10  
syscall  

.data  
.align 2  
init_matrix:            .space 400  # Allocates memory for a matrix of size 10*10 maximum, containing integers.  
submatrix:              .space 400  
final_matrix:           .space 400  
msg_dimensions_matrix:  .asciiz "Please define the dimensions of the matrix: \n"  
msg_dimensions_subm:    .asciiz "Please define the dimensions of the submatrix: \n"  
msg_fill:               .asciiz "Now, you have to fill the matrix. \n"  
msg_input:              .asciiz "Please enter an integer: \n"  
msg_leftdist:           .asciiz "Please define the left distance: \n"  
msg_upperdist:          .asciiz "Please define the upper distance: \n"  
msg_final:              .asciiz "The new matrix is: \n"  
newline:                .asciiz "\n"
```

I'm getting: line 50: Runtime exception at 0x004000c8: store address not aligned on word boundary 0x10010533

Can someone tell me why this is happening? Wasn't ".align 2" supposed to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that $a0 is not getting set to 0 in the following code:

```
input_loop_0:
    addi $v0, $0, 4
    la $a0, msg_input
    syscall
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    move $t1, $v0       # Stores user input in $t1.
    la $t7, init_matrix
    add $t7, $0, $a0  <==============  $a0 contains the (unaligned) address of msg_input
    sw $t1, 0($t7)      # Stores user input properly in matrix.
    addi $a0, $a0, 4    # Increases row counter by 4 bytes.
    bne $t7, $a3, input_loop_0
```